# mouse picking in opengl using `gluUnProject`

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, mouse-picking

I have a scene that I am rendering couple of cubes in it with openGL (program structure is not using GLUT,it is in win32 program structure but I just draw cubes with `glutSolidCube`)
now I want to select these cubes by mouse by picking. this is what I am doing:
first when the user clicks the mouse button on the scene I get the mouse position and trying to find its coordinates in scene coordinates (templateSkeletons is a skeleton I created out of cubes, nothing more):

```
if (mouse.buttonPressed(Mouse::BUTTON_LEFT))
        {
            mouse.update();
            templateSkeletons[0].selectionMode = true;
            Vector3* points;
            points = GetOGLPos();
            templateSkeletons[0].setIntersectionPoints(points[0],points[1]);
        }else
            templateSkeletons[0].selectionMode = false;
```

this is the `GerOGLPos` function that I am retrieving the coordinates in the scene (notice that I have my own camrea and its own projection matrix but I am fetching projection matrix here in this function just by calling `glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);` is this wrong and I should get my own camrea's projection matrix ? ) :

```
Vector3* GetOGLPos()
  {Vector3 pointsOnLine[2];
double mvmatrix[16];
double projmatrix[16];
int viewport[4];
double dX, dY, dZ, dClickY,zz;  
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);   
glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
dClickY = double (viewport[3] - mouse.yPos()); 
// OpenGL renders with (0,0) on bottom, mouse reports with (0,0) on top
//glReadPixels( mouse.xPos(), int(dClickY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &zz );
gluUnProject ((double) mouse.xPos(), dClickY, 0.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
pointsOnLine[0] = Vector3( (float) dX, (float) dY, (float) dZ );
gluUnProject ((double) mouse.xPos(), dClickY, 1.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
pointsOnLine[1]  = Vector3( (float) dX, (float) dY, (float) dZ );

    return pointsOnLine;
       }
```

now I suppose I have two points indicating my picking ray in the scene. now when I render the cubes I try to calculate the distance of the line created by the ray and the cube, and if it is smaller than a value I change the color of the cube to know that I picked it (jointsOfSkeleton indicates each cube that is created the skeleton nothing more, in here I am testing just the cube number 6 in array ):

```
 if(selectionMode)
        {

            distToLine  = Vector3::PointToLineDistance3D(rayPoints[0],rayPoints[1],Vector3::Vector3(jointsOfSkeleton[6].x,
                jointsOfSkeleton[6].y,jointsOfSkeleton[6].z));
            //distToLine = sqrt(distToLine);
            if(distToLine < 0.5)
                glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

            else 
                glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        }
```

when I click on irrelevant positions on the window I see the colors of cube changes, it doesn't work right, I am watching the distances on the debugger and the distances doesn't look right. and this is function I used for finding Line-point distance:

```
static float PointToLineDistance3D(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 point)
{   

    Vector3 lineDirection = b - a;
    float t = (Vector3::dot(point,lineDirection) - Vector3::dot(lineDirection,a))/(Vector3::dot(lineDirection,lineDirection));
    Vector3 direction;
    direction.x = a.x + (lineDirection.x *t) - point.x;
    direction.y = a.y + (lineDirection.y *t) - point.y;
    direction.z = a.z + (lineDirection.z *t) - point.z;

    float ShortestDistance = sqrtf((direction.x*direction.x)+(direction.y*direction.y)+(direction.z*direction.z));

    return ShortestDistance;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write the `PointToLineDistance3D`:

```
static float PointToLineDistance3D(const Vector3 &a, const Vector3 &b, const Vector3 &point){   
    Vector3 lineDirection = Vector3::normalize(b - a), pointDirection = point - a;
    float t = Vector3::dot(pointDirection,lineDirection);
    Vector3 projection = a + (lineDirection * t);

   float ShortestDistance = (projection - point).length();
   return ShortestDistance;
}
```

I made the assumption that:

- the `Vector3` class has a `length` method, with obvious meaning,
- there's a `*` operator to scale vectors,
- there's a `normalize` function as well which returns ... a normalized vector (this could also be made a method to avoid constructing an extra object).

The idea is to compute the projection of `point` on the ray and then compute the distance between the `projection` and `point`. As you can see the algorithm is slightly different from your implementation, most notably in the computation of `t`. Perhaps this is where your problem lies.

In order to test case the code I provided above, I wrote a small programme using it, which build a 3x3 wall of cubes on the XY plane, the centre of the wall being `<0,0,0>`.  I  managed to have it working without problem, even when moving the camera around. The only issue was with regard to the mouse coordinate system which goes top to bottom (ie. t_the Y mouse coord increases downward_), which is the opposit of the natural OpenGL Y axis. It requires the *SDL* library in order to compile and run.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <Vector3.h>

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600

GLuint box;
int highlight[2]; // position of the cube in the wall
const float cube_width = 5.0; 

Vector3 position(0,0,-25); // camera position

// build the cube display list
void setup_cube(){

  const float w = cube_width;

  float w0 = -w, h0 = -w, w1 = w, h1 = w;

  box = glGenLists(1);
  glNewList(box, GL_COMPILE);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
      glVertex3f(w0, h1, w0);
      glVertex3f(w0, h0, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h1, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h0, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h1, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h0, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h1, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h0, w1 );
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
      glVertex3f(w1, h1, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h1, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h1, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h1, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h0, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w0, h0, w1 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h0, w0 );
      glVertex3f(w1, h0, w1 );
    glEnd();
  glEndList();
}

void setup_scene(){

  float r = WIDTH / HEIGHT;

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum( -r, r, -1, 1, 1, 1024);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glTranslatef(position[0],position[1],position[2]);

  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void draw_scene(){

  const float w = cube_width;
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
      float x = w * 2 * i,  y = w * 2 * j;

      if (highlight[0] == i && highlight[1] == j)
         glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
      else 
         glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

      glPushMatrix ();
         glTranslatef(x,y,0);
         glCallList(box);
      glPopMatrix ();
    }
  }
}

void aim(float xm, float ym_){

  const float w = cube_width;
  float ym = HEIGHT - ym_;

  GLdouble model[16];
  GLdouble proj[16];
  GLint view[16];

  glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
  glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, proj);
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);
  highlight[0] = -5;
  highlight[1] = -5;

  for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
      float x = w * 2 * i, y = w * 2 * j;
      double ox, oy, oz;
      Vector3 centre(x,y,0);
      gluUnProject(xm, ym, 0, model, proj, view, &ox, &oy, &oz);
      Vector3 p0(ox,oy,oz);
      gluUnProject(xm, ym, 1, model, proj, view, &ox, &oy, &oz);
      Vector3 p1(ox,oy,oz);
      float d = PointToLineDistance(p0,p1,centre);
      if (d < w) {
        highlight[0] = i;
        highlight[1] = j;
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(){

  SDL_Surface *screen;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 5 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 5 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 5 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

  if ( (screen=SDL_SetVideoMode( WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL )) == NULL ) {
    SDL_Quit();
    return -1;
  }

  setup_cube();

  while (1) {
    SDL_Event event;
    setup_scene();

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
      switch(event.type){
      case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        aim(event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
        break;
      case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
        {
          switch (event.key.keysym.sym){
          case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            SDL_Quit();
            exit(1);
          case SDLK_LEFT:
            position.add(Vector3(1,0,0));
            break;
          case SDLK_RIGHT:
            position.sub(Vector3(1,0,0));
            break;
          case SDLK_UP:
            position.add(Vector3(0,0,1));
            break;
          case SDLK_DOWN:
            position.sub(Vector3(0,0,1));
            break;
          case SDLK_PAGEDOWN:
            position.add(Vector3(0,1,0));
            break;
          case SDLK_PAGEUP:
            position.sub(Vector3(0,1,0));
            break;
          }
        }
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw_scene();
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    usleep(10);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The source listed above displays correctly the cube aimed by the mouse pointer. It is possible to move around using the arrow and page up/down keys.

Comment: my `Vector3` class has your assumptions. but this modification in code didn't solve the problem. as I said I am using my default projection matrix. don't you think that I is the cause of problem? how can I use it instead of `glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);`

Comment: good insight: the code where you use your own matrix is not visible, but you probably install it in the OpenGL transformation pipeline by using `glLoadMatrix`. If that is the case, then you only need to provide that same matrix to `gluUnproject`, instead of the one you get with `glGetDouble`: it may or may not be the same matrix depending on what you do between rendering and the user interaction code. I reimplemented the function to verify it, and perhaps your code being optimized somehow, I could not see the similarity with mine.

Comment: yes as you said I insert my camera's projection matrix into pipeline using `glLoadMatrix` in initialization step but I dont use it in `glGetDoubl` when I projecting, I am going to modify that part and see what will happen.

Comment: again I got the wrong coordinations and when I click other locations in the viewport the cubes get selected :(

Comment: I also tried this `gluUnProject ((double) mymouse.x, dClickY, 1.0, templateSkeletons[0].tempMatrix, templateSkeletons[0].tempMatrixP, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
 pointsOnLine[1]  = Vector3( (float) dX, (float) dY, (float) dZ );
 Vector3 vv = g_camera.getPosition();
 pointsOnLine[0].x = vv.x;
 pointsOnLine[0].y = vv.y;
 pointsOnLine[0].z = vv.z;` I mean I called `gluUbproject` once on near plane and camera position as my two point to create ray

Comment: I am doing this `Vector3 aa = Vector3::Vector3(0.0,1.0,0.0); 

      distToLine  = Vector3::PointToLineDistance3DNEW(rayPoints[0],rayPoints[1],aa);
     if(distToLine < 0.1)
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);` and when I click right under a cube I rendered in that coordination the cube changes to red not when I click on cube itself